# Twitter Bootstrap data-toggle="tab dropdown" not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am new to twitter bootstrap(tb) and find it interesting. I am using TB in play framework for one of the client prj.

Is it possible to use a structure that looks

The drop down works if i use data-toggle="dropdown". Below is the code i used

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en"> 
<head> 
<meta charset="utf-8"> 
<title>Example tabbsable nav with Twitter Bootstrap</title> 
<meta name="description" content="Example tabable nav with Twitter Bootstrap">
<link href="@routes.Assets.at("stylesheets/bootstrap.css")" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row-fluid">
<div class="span4">
<div class="tabbable">
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
<li class="dropdown">
<a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="tab dropdown" href="#pane1">
Abonnement&nbsp;og&nbsp;bestillinger
<b class="caret"></b>
</a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">  
<li><a href="#">Behandle abonnement</a></li>  
<li><a href="#">Vis bestillinger</a></li>  
<li><a href="#">Innportering av reserverte nummer</a></li>  
</ul>  
</li>   
<li class=""><a href="#2" data-toggle="tab">Section 2</a></li>  
<li class=""><a href="#3" data-toggle="tab">Section 3</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
<div class="tab-pane" id="pane1">
<p>You are watching 1.</p>
</div>
<div class="tab-pane" id="2">
<p>You are watching 2.</p>
</div>
<div class="tab-pane" id="3">
<p>You are watching 3.</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<script src="@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/jquery.js")"></script>  
<script src="@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/bootstrap-dropdown.js")"></script>  
<script src="@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/application.js")"></script> 
<script src="@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/bootstrap-tab.js")"></script> 
</body>
</html>
```

My requirement is when I click Abonnement og bestillinger, the pane1 content - You are watching 1 should be displayed.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried to include the JS scripts in the header of your page?

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this..

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
<li class="dropdown">
  <a class="pull-right" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="caret"></span></a><a class="pull-left" data-toggle="tab" href="#pane1">Abonnement&nbsp;og&nbsp;bestillinger</a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">  
  <li><a href="#">Behandle abonnement</a></li>  
  <li><a href="#">Vis bestillinger</a></li>  
  <li><a href="#">Innportering av reserverte nummer</a></li>  
  </ul>  
</li>   
<li class=""><a href="#2" data-toggle="tab">Section 2</a></li>  
<li class=""><a href="#3" data-toggle="tab">Section 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

But, there is a formatting/spacing issue. You may need to customize the CSS styles.

<kbd>[**Demo on Bootply**](http://www.bootply.com/63813)</kbd>